# SQL Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

Error: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type nvarchar.

```
UPDATE [dbo].ForecastAccuracyKeyAccounts
SET ThreeMonthPercent = ((Actual - ThreeMonthForecast) / Actual) * 100, SixMonthPercent = ((Actual - SixMonthForecast) / Actual) * 100, 
NineMonthPercent = ((Actual - NineMonthForecast) / Actual) * 100
WHERE Actual != 0
```

Since, I am dividing by Actual, I want to ensure that Actual is not equal to zero. But when I add the statement in the WHERE CLAUSE I cannot get rid of the error.

Comment: what data types are your columns? It looks like there is something funky going on with type conversions

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Actual float; ThreeMonthPercent nvarchar(7); ThreeMonthForecast float; This worked fine before I added the Where Clause. The only error I would get is when the Actual column was 0.

Comment: Can you show the values that are causing the expression to fail?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure ... but does SQL Server guarantee the order of processing (`WHERE` before `SET`)? If not, it could evaluate the `SET` statements first before applying the `WHERE` clause. [In which case you'll need to test for `Actual=0` somehow in your `SET` statement, e.g. ... `/NULLIF(Actual,0)`]

Comment: 615.52      10357.5145          NULL I think this one is the culprit, the answer would be -1582.725906 or so. So it cannot convert it to nvarchar?

Comment: See my answer.  Use IsNull to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try `ISNULL`

```
UPDATE [dbo].ForecastAccuracyKeyAccounts

    SET ThreeMonthPercent = ((Actual - ISNULL(ThreeMonthForecast,0)) / Actual) * 100,

    SixMonthPercent = ((Actual - ISNULL(SixMonthForecast,0)) / Actual) * 100, 

    NineMonthPercent = ((Actual - ISNULL(NineMonthForecast,0)) / Actual) * 100

    WHERE Actual != 0
```

Comment: Sorry about the formatting, i'm posting from my mobile phone.  You have a NULL value for ThreeMonthForecast.  That is the problem.  Using IsNull should fix it.

Comment: This does not work, I still get the overflow error. Thank you for your help though! It's tough typing from a cellphone!

Comment: Can you increase the size of your nvarchar(7) and see if that helps.

Comment: I support change the data type as a whole? This is a percentage, so maybe change it to decimal?

Comment: Change your ThreeMonthPercent, SixmonthPercent and NineMonthPercent to float and see if that helps.

Comment: I changed the table columns to a decimal and that corrected the issue. Thanks for your help!